# How can I theme individual fields?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have views of ubercart products which are displayed in a table by standard drupal view standards. 
How can i theme individual product fields ?

views-view-field.tpl is having the complete product listed inside $output variable..
I want to solve this in a template file where all fields are available individually ..

Answer (score 0):

Inside the views-view-field.tpl.php, you can use the $row variable to get your other fields.
If you're using the Devel module, just send a dsm($row); to get the path to the fields you want to access.

For example I've this inside a views field template, to check if a user have something inside the field "twitter_account" :

```
$twitter_account = "";
if(isset($row->field_field_twitter_account[0]['raw']['value'])){
    $twitter_account = $row->field_field_twitter_account[0]['raw']['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Display Suite and DS Extras, then enable Field Templates. This gives you full control of the field markup in your view modes. It might also be a bit cleaner as well, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.